# astropy.io is not showing the figures

Tags: python

I am trying to work with astropy.io to show with kepler figures : I try everything that is said like this in the webpage http://learn.astropy.org/rst-tutorials/FITS-images.html?highlight=filtertutorials:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [2]: from astropy.io import fits

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: from astropy.utils.data import download_file

In [5]: image_file = download_file('http://data.astropy.org/tutorials/FITS-image
   ...: s/HorseHead.fits', cache=True )


In [6]: 

In [6]: hdu_list = fits.open(image_file)

In [7]: hdu_list.info()
Filename: /home/mahtab/.astropy/cache/download/py2/2c9202ae878ecfcb60878ceb63837f5f
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU     161   (891, 893)   int16   
  1  er.mask       1 TableHDU        25   1600R x 4C   [F6.2, F6.2, F6.2, F6.2]   

In [8]: image_data = hdu_list[0].data

In [9]: print(type(image_data))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

In [10]: print(image_data.shape)
(893, 891)

In [11]: plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
Out[11]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7fbd3f9f7c50>
```

it gives me the data and info but it doesn't show the figure
what should I do with :

```
Out[11]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7fbd3f9f7c50>
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I try it in Visual Studio Code, Fedora 29 terminal, and Python-3. none is working. it is said it is related to matplotlib #backend but it is not working even with changing backend

Comment: I ask because your code works fine for me - if it's run all at once. Have you tried that as well, rather than line-by-line as in your example?

Comment: yeah, I did and again nothing work. but I found the solution in https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9834 . if somebody needs it. by using ipython --pylab in terminal simply this will launch ipython configured to be able to support the matplotlib GUI backend.

Comment: Consider writing that as an answer :) Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
for those who have an issue like me that by changing backend nothing happen:
github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9834:

run this :

```
ipython --pylab
```

in the terminal and it shows the plots. this will launch ipython matplotlib GUI backend.